# Silverlight Button click Effect

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

I need to apply click effects to silverlight Button, which is when you click on button it should have click fill. What mechanism is expected.

It should be like actual button click , on clicking it should go down and on release should go up again

For Example : Save Edits Button on stack overflow

Comment: you have to create/edit the button's visual tree level elements for different click-states. you can use sketchflow to edit/create them easily

Comment: can you provide me an example or a hint

Comment: you can refer to @DNKROZ 's answer. he provided a good example.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a style for your button - in the resources section of your xaml.

See this example style

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle"  x:Name="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
      <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
              <Grid>
                  <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#D8FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#8CFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#3FFFFFFF"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                  </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                      <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1">
                          <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
                          <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
                              <Rectangle.Fill>
                                  <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                      <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                      <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                      <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                      <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                              </Rectangle.Fill>
                          </Rectangle>
                      </Grid>
                  </Border>
                  <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                  <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                  <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

You say you want a "click fill" so edit the "Pressed" Button state as required.

You can then use the style by assigning it to your button/s - by setting the buttons style property: `Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"`